# Move to other window backwards?

Tags: window

Emacs has the function other-window that lets you jump between windows. The function's documentation states that it takes an optional argument that tells the function how many windows to jump ahead.

Once upon a time, I defined a keyboard shortcut to call (other-window -1) to jump to the previous window. But at some point (GNU Emacs 25, I think), this stopped working. At first, it did not bother me much, but over time it has become a real nuisance. So if anybody knows a way to replicate that behavior, I would be very grateful!

The function I wrote looks like this:

```
(defun previous-window ()
    (interactive nil)
    (other-window -1))
```

And it is bound to a command key like so:

```
(global-set-key "\C-xp" 'previous-window)
```

The error message I get:

other-window: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive nil) (other-window -1)), 3

When I run emacs -Q and enter the function and keybinding manually, I get the same error.

Also, I have a function to switch to the previous frame:

```
(defun prev-frame ()
    (interactive nil)
    (other-frame -1))
```

*This* function works as expected.

Comment: `(other-window -1)` works fine for me, and the docstring suggests it should.  Try it without your init file (`emacs -Q`).  If it works appropriately, it's something in your init file that is interfering.

Comment: What @dan said. The question is unclear so far, so it risks being deleted. Specify what you mean by *"stopped working"*: say what happens. Show your code that binds the key. Remember that a key needs to be bound to a *command*, which means a function that has an `interactive` spec.

Comment: I can't reproduce in 26.1 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the function `previous-window` does already exist and is called by `other-window`.  You can get info about it with `C-h f previous-window` (before you define your own `previous-window`):

> previous-window is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> (previous-window &optional WINDOW MINIBUF ALL-FRAMES)
>
> ...

So the fix is simply to call your own function some other name.

```
(defun myprevious-window ()
    (interactive)
    (other-window -1))
```

Note: it turns out there is also a function `previous-frame` so your second function would fail in the same way if you call it `previous-frame` instead of `prev-frame`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that did indeed fix it! Now excuse me while I facepalm myself really hard.

Comment: Haha, frankly the error message is not very helpful, I wonder if it's because this is a C function.